# How to extend IdentityUser?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I used the following article to add ASP.NET Identity manually to a Web Forms Project:

http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project

I noticed, the registration page just asks for a User name and Password, but I want to also add First Name, Last Name, Email, etc.  I tried creating my own class called ApplicationUser that extends IdentityUser, but this causes and error with mapping when I call `IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);`:

`Additional information: Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType 'WebFormsIdentity.IdentityExtensions.ApplicationUser'.`

Most of the examples I see in adding more data to IdentityUser has to do with code first, but I generated my memebership db first by running aspnet_regsql from the command line to generate the aspnetdb database.  How can I add extra information when registering a user?

Comment: You still need to update the database to contain the new properties, wether you use Code First or Database First.

Comment: @HåkanFahlstedt - Do I just need to go in an update one single table and add the column I want?

Comment: @HåkanFahlstedt - I tried this, but 2 things happened, one it required me to drop and re-create the table AspNetUsers along with others and foremost, it did not work, I still got the mapping error from above.

Comment: If you look at your .edmx file you need a mapping to the ApplicationUser class, as this class is inheriting the IdentityUser. So I would create a new table for the ApplicationUser and then do the mapping.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? I'm actually following that same tutorial. Right now, though, I can't seem to get my project to understand what **WebFormsIdentity** is in the **Startup** class.

Comment: I was following the same tutorial and could not figure things out! I ended up creating a separate table for the additional user data that I needed to add. Not an answer to your question, but at least it works...